# How do I compute the expectation of the following function with respect to a Multivariate Gaussian distribution?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, expectation

The function is as follows:
$\boldsymbol{1}_{n}^{T} \exp\left(\boldsymbol{X\beta} \right).$
So the expectation that I want to compute is
$\operatorname{E}_{\boldsymbol{\beta}} \left[\boldsymbol{1}_{n}^{T} \exp \left(\boldsymbol{X\beta} \right) \right]$
where $\boldsymbol{X}$ is a $n \times p$ matrix and $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ is a $p \times 1$ column vector and $\boldsymbol{\beta} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \Sigma \right)$.
($\boldsymbol{1}_{n}^{T}$ is a $n \times 1$ column vector with $n$ ones and $\exp$ is an element-wise operator.)

Comment: What do  you know about $X$, is deterministic?

Comment: @CarlosMendoza yes, that is actually the design matrix under a regression model. So it's deterministic.

Comment: You may find useful [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89970/exponential-of-a-standard-normal-random-variable) post.

Comment: @CarlosMendoza wow, that comment immediately solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

$X \beta$ is also a normal distribution, with mean $X \mu$ and covariance $X\Sigma X^T$.

So, $[\exp(X \beta)]_i \sim LogNormal([X \mu]_i, [X \Sigma X^T]_{ii})$, and you can calculate out its [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), call it $\xi_i$.

Then, $E[1^T \exp (X \beta) ] = \sum_i E \xi_i$ by linearity of expectation.